# Can someone show why this tensor product of matrices is correct?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products

I am trying to understand tensor products better. I decided to find an example and try to understand it. I read somewhere the the following is a correct application of the tensor product for these matrices: 
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
 & a_{1,2}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
 \\
a_{2,1}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
 & a_{2,2}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}b_{1,1} & a_{1,1}b_{1,2} & a_{1,2}b_{1,1} & a_{1,2}b_{1,2} \\
a_{1,1}b_{2,1} & a_{1,1}b_{2,2} & a_{1,2}b_{2,1} & a_{1,2}b_{2,2} \\
a_{2,1}b_{1,1} & a_{2,1}b_{1,2} & a_{2,2}b_{1,1} & a_{2,2}b_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1}b_{2,1} & a_{2,1}b_{2,2} & a_{2,2}b_{2,1} & a_{2,2}b_{2,2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
I gather this is known as block decomposition.

According to one definition I read, a tensor product can be defined as follows:

> Let $U$ and $V$ be arbitrary vector spaces. Then the *tensor product* is a vector space $U \otimes V$ such that
>
> 1. There is a bilinear map $i: U \times V \rightarrow U \otimes V$
> 2. Given any bilinear map $f: U \times V \rightarrow W$, there is a unique linear map $L_f: U \otimes V \rightarrow W$ such that $L_f \circ i = f$.

**My Question:**

Usually, when I read the definition of something, I immediately see how to use it. But if I read the definition of a tensor product and was given the two matrices on the left, I would have no idea what to do. I don't see how, based on the definition, I know that block decomposition is the right answer. **Can someone explain from the definition why this is the correct solution given the tensor product of matrices on the left?**

Comment: The matrix you computed is the representation of the tensor product in the basis $(e_1 \otimes e_1, e_1 \otimes e_2, e_2\otimes e_1, e_2\otimes e_1)$. The universal property you name is naturally hard to work with because it doesn't give an explicit construction.

Comment: Does that mean the definition is incomplete? What would be an example of an explicit construction?

Comment: The definition _is_ complete but it classifies the tensor product by a universal property and only up to isomorphism. The explicit construction is just giving the basis elements I listed and noting that they are independent. $\otimes$ doesn't commute.

Comment: Also note your 2. contained a minor notational mistake messing everything up.

Comment: Your first comment repeats $e_2 \otimes e_1$, I assume that wasn't intentional.

Comment: It was meant to be $e_2\otimes e_2$ of course. Thanks!